# Using Eclipe Collections with Android - build.gradle fails

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, eclipse-collections

For an Android project which I'm developing I need* to use the Eclipse Collections framework. So I integrated it to my `build.gradle` according to their ["get started"](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/#start), and imported the needed libraries. The problem is that when I tried to run the app on my Android device it fails with the message:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   More than one file was found with OS independent path 'LICENSE-EDL-1.0.txt'

I did some googling and got to a few questions here at Stackoverflow with similar (though not identical) problems, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me (most of them suggested to add `packagingOptions` to `build.gradle`). If it matters anyhow - my app uses OpenCV4Android, and I'm developing it in Android Studio.

In addition, just to be clear, everything works fine without the Eclipse-Collections additions..

Here's of my app's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.coftest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-api:9.0.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary330')
}
```

* it's not a must-have, but it makes my code more simple and elegant, and I would really like to have that.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your gradle :

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-EDL-1.0.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working... :( Just to be clear, I added it in the `android{}` section of my gradle

Comment: replace this : compile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-api:9.0.0'
compile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections:9.0.0'
testCompile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-testutils:9.0.0'
compile 'org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-forkjoin:9.0.0'

Comment: Could you please edit you answer (add your comment to your answer)? It's quite hard to understand exactly what to do... thanks